# Rest API service

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

http://dev.eternal/rest/all/schema?services=all, gives all services,

but what if I want to grab only customer service? how can I do it?
Plus, how to create a service and call just the desired API's?

Thanks!

I have searched for a while and didn't find out this answers...

I'm using magento 2.4.5-p1

Comment: You can use https://mage2gen.com/ for generate a module structure with API calls easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/generate-local/

Answers my questions.